# How to append table head only once when loop through the JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to only once append table head when looping(search) through the JSON array?When I try this, every time when starting search table-head append for every match,  although two products belong the same group.

> HTML

```
</select>
Search: <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
<div id="place"></div>
```

> Java Script

```
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

 $('#search').keyup(function(event){
 $('#place').html('');
 if (event.keyCode == 8) {
          $('#place').hide('')
          }else{
          $('#place').show('') 
          }
 $('#state').val('');
 var searchField = $('#search').val();
 var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
```

LOOP JSON

```
  $.getJSON('product.json', function(result) {
   //LOOP JSON
```

TABLE HEAD to appears only once in the search.

```
  $.each(result, function(key, value){
       //TABLE HEAD this need to apperas only one
       var text = '';
       text +='<table class="table" width="610" cellpadding="3" 
        cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#cccccc">';

       text +='<tr>';
       text +='<th width="20%" bgcolor="#aaaaaa" align="left"><font 
       color="#ffffff">Model</font></th>';
       text +='<th width="25%" bgcolor="#aaaaaa"><font color="#ffffff">CODEC 
       Supported</font></th>';

       text +='</tr>';

       text +='<p style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; color:#2773ba; 
       margin-bottom:5px">'+value.brand+'</p>'; 
       // END TABLE HEAD

       //END OF TABLE HEAD -START TABLE BODY

       // TABLE BODY is filling with data from json

      if (value.brand.search(expression) != -1 || 
      value.model.search(expression) != -1 || 
      value.CODECSupported.search(expression) != -1  )
       {

       text += '<tr>'
       text += '<td colspan="9" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-
       weight:bold; color:#3399cc">'+value.type+'</td>'
       text += '</tr>'
       text += '<tr>'
       text += '<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">'+value.model+'</td>'
       text += '<td align="center" 
       bgcolor="#FFFFFF">'+value.CODECSupported+'</td>'
       text += '</tr>'
       text += '</table>'

       $('#place').append(text)


      }


      });   
      });
      });
```

END OF BODY

```
  })
```

Comment: Start and end the table outside of the loop...only use loop for the data rows

Comment: You only loop through the content. You could use a flag to add the header only once, but it will be evaluated every time it loops!

Answer (score 1):

You can either do the table creation outside of the loop (have just the generated data inside the loop), or you can have a boolean that checks whether you have went through the loop once

Example pseudo-ish code:

```
passed = false;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    // some code happening
    if(!passed){
        // here add the headers
        passed = true;
    }
    else{
        //do the rest
    }
    // other code happening
}
```

I would recommend having the table setup outside the loop since it would be more efficient, because with this pseudo code you will have an extra check on each iteration of the loop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for code, I try myself something similar but   I can 't see where the error is, now there is no header